# Using CSS Modules with Gastby and Storybook

Tags: reactjs, sass, gatsby, storybook, css-modules

I recently switch my project from Next.js to Gastby.js and my CSS module imports stopped working. After some investigation, I noticed I had to change my `import` statements to use a new syntax for Gastby. The problem is that Storybook doesn't recognize that syntax.

Original Syntax (Next, Storybook):

```
import root from "./Header.module.scss";
```

New Syntax (Gastby)

```
import {root} from "./Header.module.scss";
```

I have tried looking into changing setting in the Gastby config plugin section but to no avail. My next step is to look into making some sort of preprocessor to search and replace the lines depending on the context but I am not sure if that is the right move.